# What is quasineutral in plasma physics?

Tags: collision, plasma-physics, gas, ions, quasiparticles

What is quasineutral gas? In plasma physics, what exactly quasineutral means? In definition of plasma, it is written that plasma is a quasineutral gas of charged and neutral particles which exhibit collective behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put it simply:

Plasma is described as a quasi-neutral gas consisting of ions and electrons. You know that electrons are negatively charged and ions (typically ionised by losing an electron) are positive. To sustain a stable plasma, it must be subject to an electric field (lets say between an alternating bias of electrodes) and at a gas pressure. The alternating field is accelerating the electrons rapidly in the direction of the field, but the ions are more massive and more-or-less move at random due to their higher inertia.

Now the definition of "quasi-" basically means something is '*apparently what it says it is, but not really*'. So when we think of a plasma, it is fluctuating between net-negative and net-positive charge very quickly with all these charges flying about but if you squint and take an average it *looks neutral, but not really*.

That is what quasi-neutral means, macroscopically it is easier to say it is "pretty much neutral", rather than try to put a name to the high energy chaos it takes to sustain a plasma.

Answer (score 1):

Quasi-neutrality in a [plasma frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasma_oscillation) is just saying that the following holds on distances larger than the the [Debye length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debye_length):
$$
n_{e} = \sum_{s} \ Z_{s} \ n_{s}  \tag{0}
$$
where $n_{s}$ is the number density of electrons, $Z_{s}$ is the charge state of ion species $s$, and $n_{s}$ is the number density of ion species $s$.